# bc within perl fails to get going

Tags: perl, unix

I am trying to run the `bc` unix command within Perl but that seems really hard right now. I am using `bc` because the numbers I am using are beyond 64bit in size. Here's a code snippet.

```
$temp_addr = "A5A5A5A5A5A5A5A5";
$temp_data = "82100000";
my $bc_addr = `echo \"ibase=16;obase=16;($temp_addr/8)\" | bc`;
my $bc_data = `echo \"ibase=16;obase=16;($temp_data*200)\" | bc`;
die "$bc_data, $bc_addr";
```

The output for the code when I run it is something like...

```
02 08 20 08 03 09 14 ,
 02 00 14 05 04 06 12 13 04 04 15 18 07 11 15 02 00
```

Now I was expecting the o/p in hex and a valid one at that. This one flies over my head. When I run bc in the shell directly things are just fine.

Comment: Is [`use bignum;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bignum.html) not an option?

Answer (score 2):

Set `obase=16` before `ibase=16` and it will work as a charm. Otherwise you are setting the obase to 0x16, which is not what you want.